# Initializing an object based on values in file

Tags: c++, json, class

I have the following JSON-file:

```
{
    "var": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": "a",
        "d" :3,
        "e" :"b",
        "f": 12,
        "g": 13,
        "h": 14
    }
}
```

This I read using nlohmann's JSON library. Here is a working example, where I read the JSON-file manually and use it to set the member variables of an object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"
using namespace std;

class
    Test
{
  private:
  public:
    int a, b, d, f, g, h;
    string c, e;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream input_json("tmp.json");
    nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(input_json);

    Test test;
    test.a = j["var"]["a"];
    test.b = j["var"]["b"];
    test.c = j["var"]["c"];
    test.d = j["var"]["d"];
    test.e = j["var"]["e"];
    test.f = j["var"]["f"];
    test.g = j["var"]["g"];
    test.h = j["var"]["h"];

    return 0;   
}
```

**Question:** Say my JSON-structure has +10 variables. Is there a way to automatize the process of initializing an object with the values I read from the JSON-file or does it have to be typed in manually like above?

Comment: Why not just put your code in `main` into a constructor `Test::Test(std::string filename)`, replacing `test.a` with `a` or `this->a`, etc? Is that what you mean by automate? Unless there is a pattern to the JSON variable names (e.g. completely alphabetic as indicated here) I think you have to write some manual code like this at least once...

Comment: std::map? depends how much your input format can change

Comment: c++ doesn't have native reflection, You might use some library to allow to add reflexivity and then write generic code.